# Enable / Disable 2nd level cache in Apache ignite, Spring boot

Tags: spring-boot, caching, ignite

Do we have any specific way/configuration or property to enable or disable 2nd level of caching for Apache ignite using Spring Boot ?

Below property has no effect on the caching part when it is with Apache ignite.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache=true
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `ignite-hibernate` module to classpath and configure the corresponding caches.

Refer to the following documentation page: https://apacheignite-mix.readme.io/docs/hibernate-l2-cache#l2-cache-configuration